# Cisco ASA VPN Uptime

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa

I need to be able to see how long a VPN tunnel has been up from my ASA.

sh crypto ipsec sa peer xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx doesn't show me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> show vpn-sessiondb l2l filter name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | incl Duration

Will show you duration for that tunnel

Answer (score -1):

Use Command

" show vpn-sessiondb l2l"

Comment: This has already (better)  answered six years ago...